# Hexadecimal to ASCII string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, hex, ascii

I have this pandas datafreme

```
data1_txt = """
Name
0x41
0x4a
0x47
"""
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(data1_txt))
```

As you can see it's in Hex and I need to convert it to ASCII character. Hence, I need it to look like this

```
data1_txt = """
Name
A
J
G
"""
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(data1_txt))
```

I can do this in plain python, but I can't do it in Pandas. Aný help is very much appreciated

Comment: I don't know pandas, but for single value it would be `chr(int("0x41", 16))` (parse "0x41" as base 16 integer, then get character with that ascii/unicode value). You or someone might know how to map it to entire column/df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda function or lsit comprehension:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].map(lambda x: chr(int(x, 16)))
#alternatives
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: chr(int(x, 16)))
df['Name'] = [chr(int(x, 16)) for x in df['Name']]
print (df)
  Name
0    A
1    J
2    G
```

Another idea:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].map(lambda x: bytes.fromhex(x[2:]).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks, works like magic! I will accept the answer as correct as soon as I am allowed.